# Can I click a button programmatically for a predefined intent?

Tags: android, button, click, android-intent

I need the button click of the intent ACTION_SEND.
Here there is no need of displaying UI.
Can I get the "Send" button click from the MMS-SMSProvider in Android?

Answer (score 280, accepted):

You can click a button programmatically by using the `button.performClick()` method.

Comment: Hint: Reference your button using findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);

Answer (score 54):

If your button includes any animation, you'll need to perform the click and then invalidate each step after performClick.  Here's how:

```
 button.performClick();
 button.setPressed(true); 
 button.invalidate(); 
 button.setPressed(false); 
 button.invalidate();
```

On occasion I've also had to introduce delay to get the animation to show.  Like this:

```
 //initiate the button
 button.performClick();
 button.setPressed(true); 
 button.invalidate(); 
 // delay completion till animation completes
 button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {  //delay button 
     public void run() {  
        button.setPressed(false); 
        button.invalidate();
        //any other associated action
     }
 }, 800);  // .8secs delay time
```

Answer (score 12):

```
button.callOnClick();
```

this one can also be used

Comment: API level 15 or higher required

Comment: `callOnClick()` doesn't make a clicking sound which is what I needed. While `performClick()` makes a sound.